# Is there a way to effectively mix and match DOM elements and jQuery selectors?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dom, jquery-selectors

I would like to perform jQuery operations on event targets: if some mouses over one specific DIV in an LI, I would like to run a jQuery (UI) effect on anothjer specific DIV descendant of the LI.

I can work around the difficulty easily enough by assigning ID's or other fields to the LI (in fact I have done this with a `data-*` element), have the handler look at event.target's DNA, and construct a jQuery identifier string that will work straightforwardly. But this can't be the preferred way.

If you have several different elements that could be selected, and you want to do jQuery selector-style identification and manipulation on event.target as called by a jQuery event handler, what is the preferred way? Or is it oddly enough the preferred way to assign all LI's an ID and then construct a pure-string jQuery selector, as opposed to referencing event.target and some identifiers?

(I also see a way to do this by DOM manipulation, but raw DOM manipulation is rarely a method of choice.)

Comment: Maybe if you showed some basic HTML with the problem you face we could help you with an answer.

Comment: You can use `childNodes` property for manipulating those, if you provide fiddle I can provide that as a code